# HikariCP- How to use dataSource.logWriter

Tags: java, logging, hikaricp

HikariCP [Github page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/) have the following code:

```
props.put("dataSource.logWriter", new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

But I'm getting NullPointerException beacuse LogWriter isn't supported,

[DriverDataSource](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/f005a4769ff77d03fb7e86903c5978a35e9ccb96/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/util/DriverDataSource.java) final HikariCP class:

```
@Override
public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException
{
   throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
}

@Override
public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter logWriter) throws SQLException
{
   throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
}
```

Is this solution for updating HikariCP logging is irrelevant?

I didn't get any answer in [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hikari-cp/o6rL_b364ug)

**EDIT**

Hikari initialization code uses [PoolBase](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java) which is initializing datasource with `DriverDataSource` (which doesn't support logWriter):

```
else if (jdbcUrl != null && ds == null) {
     ds = new DriverDataSource(jdbcUrl, driverClassName, dataSourceProperties, username, password);
```

I must send `jdbcUrl` in Oracle and I failed `setDataSourceClassName` in conjunction with `setDriverClassName`

Comment: There is no `DriverDataSource` class in Hikari... Are you sure you are using the proper classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/f005a4769ff77d03fb7e86903c5978a35e9ccb96/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/util/DriverDataSource.java

Comment: Ok, my bad. Nonetheless that is the wrong class as you should us the `HikariDataSource`. As also shown in the aforementioned documentation you yourself linked too. As that is a proper connection pool whereas the `DriverDataSource` isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, I'll check how the configuration effected this change

Comment: @M.Deinum actually `PoolBase` is initializing it with `DriverDataSource` .see my updated question

Comment: You use either `setDataSourceClassName` or `setDriverClassName` but not both. Also when using `setDataSourceClassName` you shouldn't nbe setting the `jdbcUrl` but rather use the specific datasource properties to configure the connection.

Comment: I must send `setDriverClassName` therefore I can't use `logWriter`

Comment: Then there is no solution... Why do you need to set the driverclassname (which is actually not even recommended as that implies the use of a `jdbcUrl`).

Comment: @M.Deinum if I use only `jdbcUrl` it doesn't find driver although it exists

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `jdbcUrl` but rather use the `setDataSourceClassName` and configure the underlying `DataSource` using the custom properties.